# d3.js problems with reading dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am trying to solve this error since 2 days now not sure any more how to solve this. I get this error white trying to add data to the visualization

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

This seems to be related to dataset. But no matter what I do I get this error if I console.log dataset outside checkit function(see below) it returns undefined.

Data

```
[ {
    "Continent":"Asia.Oceania",
    "Country_Names":"Viet Nam",
    "Total":142.9
  },
  {
    "Continent":"Asia.Oceania",
    "Country_Names":"Yemen",
    "Total":20
  },
  {
    "Continent":"Misc",
    "Country_Names":"World marine bunkers",
    "Total":602.2
  },
  {
    "Continent":"Misc",
    "Country_Names":"World aviation bunkers",
    "Total":477.8
  }
]
```

code

```
var svg_0 = d3.xml("drawing.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    d3.select("#viz").node().appendChild(importedNode);



var dataset;

function checkIt(data){
for (var i in data) {
            var data_clean;
            data_clean = data[i].Total
            dataset = data_clean
            console.log(dataset) //returns data
        }

        }
    console.log(dataset)//returns undefined


    d3.json("data.json", checkIt);


    var svg =  d3.select("#level_0")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.json("data.json", checkIt);` is an asynchronous operation ([check syntax here for example](http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html)). In short it means that at some point of your code execution `dataset` variable is literally **undefined yet**. Then, later it is defined, but it's too late.

This means that you need to be sure that dataset is defined when starting using it. For example you can move usage to checkIt callback like so:

```
  var dataset;
    function checkIt(data){
     var data_clean = []; //prepared variable for clear data
    for (var i in data) {
      data_clean.push(data[i].Total);
      }
  //move initialisation here, to be sure dataset is there
  var svg =  d3.select("#level_0")
               .selectAll("path")
               .data(data_clean);  
  }
//other code here...
d3.json("data.json", checkIt);
//other code here...
```

Comment: after moving d3.json("data.json", checkIt); at the last position in the code I still get this error. I think it is because var dataset cannot get data outside checkit function not sure how to do it though

Comment: Try putting 'var svg = ....' All that block into 'checkIt' function. That's what is the main proposal.

Comment: after that I get this error Uncaught TypeError: d3.select(...).selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).attr is not a function

Comment: What you get in console before this error ? Is your data 'dataset' an array ?

Comment: I dont think dataset is an array because (when console.log from outside for loop)returns only one (last value from json file) from the data maybe this is what is causing the problem. While console.log(dataset) from inside for function returns an array

Comment: please try the updated function 'checkIt' code. what I've tried to do - create empty array and extract all Total values from original data and then pass that to d3;